# Toggle next hidden div on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup. I want to toggle the `expanded` div when clicking the `expander` link. I only want to expand the div directly next to the link though. How can I do this?

```
<a class="expander" href="#"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here
</div>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
$('.expander').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('expanded').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next` instead. I think this should work:

```
$('.expander').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.expanded').first().toggle();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

Use next instead of siblings. Here's the solution:

```
$('.expander').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('expanded').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

You could use the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) jquery method:
So your jquery would look like:

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Note. Since the next ***only*** gets the 'next element', there's no need for the `.first()` method call.

**From the documentation:**

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

So this will only choose the next sibling element.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.expander').click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="expander" href="#">press 1</a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here 1
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#">press 2</a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here 2
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#">press 3</a>
<div class="expanded">
    content here 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create this using toggle visibility instead of toggle display:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    //call the function toggleVisibility
    toggleVisibility(this);
  });
});

function toggleVisibility(obj) {
  //declare a variable to get visibility of element
  //with class expanded
  var vis = $(obj).next().css('visibility');
  //return the visibility, if is hidden return visible to toggle
  return $(obj).next().css('visibility', vis === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

```css
.expanded {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="expander" href="#">id</a>

<div class="expanded">content here</div>
<a class="expander" href="#">id</a>

<div class="expanded">content here</div>
<a class="expander" href="#">id</a>

<div class="expanded">content here</div>
```